# Comparing multiple variables in more than two groups with t.test

Tags: r, loops, purrr, t-test, broom

I tried to do a t-test comparing values between time1/2/3.. and threshold.
here is my data frame:

```
time.df1<-data.frame("condition" =c("A","B","C","A","C","B"), 
"time1" = c(1,3,2,6,2,3) ,
"time2" = c(1,1,2,8,2,9) ,
"time3" = c(-2,12,4,1,0,6),
"time4" = c(-8,3,2,1,9,6),
"threshold" = c(-2,3,8,1,9,-3))
```

and I tried to compare each two values by:

```
time.df1%>% 
select_if(is.numeric)  %>%
purrr::map_df(~ broom::tidy(t.test(. ~ threshold)))
```

However, I got this error message

```
 Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'threshold' not found
```

So, I tried another way (maybe it is wrong)

```
time.df2<-time.df1%>%gather(TF,value,time1:time4)
time.df2%>% group_by(condition) %>% do(tidy(t.test(value~TF, data=.)))
```

sadly, I got this error. Even I limited the condition to only two levels (A,B)

```
 Error in t.test.formula(value ~ TF, data = .) : grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels
```

I wish to loop t-test over each time column to threshold column per condition, then using `broom::tidy` to get the results in tidy format. My approaches apparently aren't working, any advice is much appreciated to improve my codes.

Comment: Do you want to be doing ANOVA instead?

Comment: What is `time.df1`? Typo? Did you mean `time1.df`?

Comment: Also, you need to declare your dependencies...

Comment: I fixed the typo, thanks! Can you be more specific about the declaration of my dependencies? cheers!

Comment: Dependencies refer to the package libraries you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative route would be to define a function with the required options for t.test() up front, then create data frames for each pair of variables (i.e. each combination of 'time*' and 'threshold') and nesting them into list columns and use map() combined with relevant functions from 'broom' to simplify the outputs.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

ttestfn <- function(data, ...){
  # amend this function to include required options for t.test
  res = t.test(data$resp, data$threshold)
  return(res)
}   

df2 <-   
time.df1 %>% 
  gather(time, "resp", - threshold, -condition) %>% 
  group_by(time) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(ttests = map(data, ttestfn),
         glances = map(ttests, glance))
# df2 has data frames, t-test objects and glance summaries 
# as separate list columns
```

Now it's easy to query this object to extract what you want

```
df2 %>% 
unnest(glances, .drop=TRUE)
```

However, it's unclear to me what you want to do with 'condition', so I'm wondering if it is more straightforward to reframe the question in terms of a GLM (as camille suggested in the comments: ANOVA is part of the GLM family).

Reshape the data, define 'threshold' as the reference level of the 'time' factor and the default 'treatment' contrasts used by R will compare each time to 'threshold':

```
time.df2 <- 
  time.df1 %>% 
  gather(key = "time", value = "resp", -condition) %>% 
  mutate(time = fct_relevel(time, "threshold")) # define 'threshold' as baseline

fit.aov <- aov(resp ~ condition * time, data = time.df2)
summary(fit.aov)
summary.lm(fit.aov) # coefficients and p-values
```

Of course this assumes that all subjects are independent (i.e. there are no repeated measures). If not, then you'll need to move on to more complicated procedures. Anyway, moving to appropriate GLMs for the study design should help minimise the pitfalls of doing multiple t-tests on the same data set.

Answer (score 1):

We could remove the `threshold` from the `select` and then reintroduce it by creating a `data.frame` which would go into the formula object of `t.test`

```
library(tidyverse)
time1.df %>% 
   select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
   select(-threshold) %>%
   map_df(~ data.frame(time = .x, time1.df['threshold']) %>% 
           broom::tidy(t.test(. ~ threshold)))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion. I got the error message `tidy.data.frame' is deprecated.` about the reintroduced data.frame, do you mean the df I introduce to  `time1.df` or a new one? thanks a lot.

Comment: @Hanscot  I am not getting any errors with the data `time.df1` (name changed in your post).  What is the version of `purrr`, `dplyr` you are using?

Comment: Hi akrun, the version of `purrr` is 0.2.5 and 1.2.2 for `dplyr`. So you didn't get  same warning messages as I did `1: 'tidy.data.frame' is deprecated.
See help("Deprecated")` when you run this code? Also, do you get the p-value as the outcome? thanks a lot for your advice!

Comment: @Hanscot  the purrr version is same for me, but i have `0.7.6` for `dplyr`

Comment: Hi @akrun, thanks! it works now. sorry to ask why ttest outcome isn't including the p-value (whether time1/2.. differs significantly to its threshold)?? cheers!